Case when with distinct value
I need to calculate how many distinct customers have visited in the tp.places per month and i've tried three different solutions with no luck. What am i missing out?
SELECT
    DISTINCT tp.place,
    tp.brand,
    SUM (CASE WHEN kr.calendar_key BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-31' THEN 1 END) as 1st,
    SUM (CASE WHEN kr.calendar_key BETWEEN '2024-02-01' AND '2024-02-29' THEN DISTINCT kr.customer_key END) as 2nd
    SUM (CASE WHEN kr.calendar_key BETWEEN '2024-03-01' AND '2024-03-31' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT kr.customer_key) END) as 3rd,
FROM
    orders.f_receipts kr
    INNER JOIN dim.d_place_of_business tp ON tp.business_key = kr.business_key
WHERE
    ...

I've tried three different solution and hoped something like this:
Place   Jan   Feb   March
nr1     1150  900   1300
nr2     800   990   700
etc.

Edited the code to look more readable. Also the desired output.


First Convert the dates to month 2. Group by on tp.Place and Month column then perform aggregate


what flavor of sql is this?

I'm using redshift with tableplus

Don't use SUM, use COUNT(DISTINCT) when you want to count distinct customers.
SELECT
    tp.place,
    tp.brand,
    COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN kr.calendar_key BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-31' THEN kr.customer_key END) as january,
    COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN kr.calendar_key BETWEEN '2024-02-01' AND '2024-02-29' THEN kr.customer_key END) as february,
    COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN kr.calendar_key BETWEEN '2024-03-01' AND '2024-03-31' THEN kr.customer_key END) as march,
    ...
FROM
    orders.f_receipts kr
    INNER JOIN dim.d_place_of_business tp ON tp.business_key = kr.business_key
WHERE
    ...
GROUP BY tp.place, tp.brand
ORDER BY tp.place, tp.brand;

